# 'Item' vs 'Product' - Meaning different?

Tags: meaning

'Item'  vs  'Product'

When I sell a thing(physical) What word should I use?

Curious exact different

Comment: It depends on what it is, and in what context it is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Items* are typically things that are part of a list or collection of some kind.

*Products*, in the sense you are thinking of, are things that are produced.

Since things sold in a store are on the inventory list of the store, we often call them items. And since they're often things that are produced by factories or farms, we also can call them products.

But if I made a list of all the rocks in my back yard, then those rocks would be items in the list, but they wouldn't be products.

Finding an example of a product that isn't an item is harder, but maybe something made one-of-a-kind, like,

> The Curiosity Mars Rover was the product of 10 years of effort at NASA.

Answer (score 0):

As I know and read it before there is a big different between these two nouns, I have got many English translation of ***item*** first and afterwards at next part translation for ***product*** will be explained to you.
A separate article or particular, a separate piece of information or news, as a short piece in a newspaper or broadcast. Slang: something suitable for a news paragraph or as a topic of gossip, especially something that is sensational or scandalous, a word formerly used in communications to represent the letter I. Older Use. an intimation or hint. 
aforementioned translation were exactly for ***Item*** as a noun as you took in ,there were nothing approximate to the word you mentioned but let me tell you concerning ***product*** :
thing produced by labor, a person or thing produced by or resulting from a process, as a natural, social, or historical one; result, the totality of goods or services that a company makes available; output, Chemistry. a substance obtained from another substance through chemical change, in mathematics:  the result obtained by multiplying two or more quantities together. 
if you understand my meant you do highly agree that for the question you asked above the absolute noun to use in your statement is ***product***.
I am hopeful my explanation could be useful to response the question you had in your mind.